# Angular 1: Double console output

Tags: angularjs

I called method `console.log(data)` in my controller only once but the output in console is displayed twice.

[image]

This is the controller:

```
taskAppControllers.controller('ToDoCtrl', ['$scope',
  function($scope){
    $scope.loadToDoItems = function(){
      var data = ls.get("toDoData");
      if (data == null) data = [];
      console.log(data);
    }
    $scope.toDoItems = $scope.loadToDoItems();
    $scope.addToDoItem(){};
}]);
```

And this is the view:

```
<div ng-controller="ToDoCtrl">
  <form>
    <input type="text" ng-model="toDoItem">
    <input type="submit" ng-click="addToDoItem()">
  </form>
</div>
```

The router:

```
var TaskApp = angular.module('TaskApp', [
  'ngRoute',
  'taskAppControllers'
]);

TaskApp.config(['$routeProvider',
  function($routeProvider){
  $routeProvider.
      when('/home', {
        templateUrl: "partials/home.html",
        controller: "HomeCtrl",
        title: 'Home',
        icon: 'ion-android-menu',
        link: '#/main-menu'
      }).
      when('/main-menu', {
        templateUrl: "partials/main-menu.html",
        controller: "MainMenuCtrl",
        title: 'Main menu',
        icon: 'ion-close',
        link: '#/'
      }).
      when('/todo', {
        templateUrl: "partials/todo.html",
        controller: "ToDoCtrl",
        title: 'To do',
        icon: 'ion-close',
        link: '#/main-menu'
      }).
      otherwise({
        redirectTo: "/home"
      });
  }]);
```

Comment: `$scope.loadToDoItems()` doesn't return anything. Presumably you're calling or triggering it somehow other than `$scope.toDoItems = $scope.loadToDoItems()` which runs when your controller is created. Can't see an `addToDoItem()` method on your `$scope` either

Comment: @Phil Yeah because I deleted it temporary.

Comment: Where else do you call `loadToDoItems()`? How is the view loaded / included?

Comment: @Phil it is included as partial. This is the only place it is called. If I rename it to for example toDoItems423412423423 , nothing really changes, it still gives double output, so I am pretty sure it's called only once.

Comment: @Kunok here it the jsFiddle https://jsfiddle.net/j1Lyqfev/5/ for your issue, its getting executed only once. Can you please update jsFiddle to replicate your issue.

Comment: On the 8th line, did you mean to write `$scope.toDoItem = ...`? I see `toDoItem` in the view, but nowhere else in the controller

Comment: That view is rendered twice. Use console.log("I am called") as controller first line which will confirm you the controller is called twice. Then its your routing issue

Comment: @AlaksandarJesusGene I included router code into my question and it is true what you say.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not use `ng-controller` in your HTML because you are using routing. You should use `ng-view`.

Check the routing documentation, [like here](https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_07).

Maybe your controller is being executed once from the HTML and once from the router.